# why the time complexity of a single node to search is O(1) and not O(logn)?

Tags: b-tree

in the search in the fourth-order B-tree with n elements stored,why the time complexity of a single node to search is O(1) and not O(logn)? Shouldn't the time complexity of finding a single node be O(logn) ? Plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

Let's review search only in one NODE? It is Significant.

B-tree has array of childs. In common case search in Array has O(n) complexivity.

If you sort childs and use binary search you will get O(logn) complexivity.

So, in common case search in B-tree has O(logn) complexivity.
In Worse case it will has O(n). There are 2 cases:

1. When all elements are stored in first node in non sorted array.
2. All nodes has only one child. Then it will be the list.

Answer (score 0):

[B-tree definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree#Definition) introduces a factor `m` to represent maximum number of children a single node can have, and maximum number of keys that can be stored in one single node is `m - 1`. Also `m < N`, where `N` is number of nodes in a B-tree.

The precise searching time at one single node is :

- `O(log(m))`, if all keys inside a single node is sorted (so you can perform binary search on that).
- `O(m)`, if they're NOT sorted in a single node. (so perform linear search)

However, `m` does NOT depend on `N`, and `m` should be considered as constant because once `m` is determined, it is unlikely dynamically changed as input size grows. (unlike `N`, `N` would grow to certain volume according to the input size) Constants like `m` can be dropped in [Big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiplication_by_a_constant), therefore both of the searching time as mentioned above (`O(m)` and `O(log(m))`) can be considered as `O(1)`

Sidenote: [This](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/59456) also provides clear explanation about the search time analysis.